# C++ no match for operator<< Error

Tags: c++

I'm nearing the end of an intro class and I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on here. First, the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    double id = 0.0;
    double rate = 0.0;
    double hours = 0.0;
    double gross = 0.0;

    ifstream wData;
    wData.open("workers.txt", ios::in);

    if (wData.is_open())
    {

    for (int count = 0; count < 8; count = count + 1)
    {

        wData << id << rate << hours;
        gross = rate * hours;
        cout << "Employee ID: " << id << "Gross Pay: " << gross << endl;
     }
     wData.close();
     }
     else
     {
         cout << "The file could not be opened." << endl;
         }


    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Next, the error:

```
41 no match for 'operator<<' in 'wData << id'
```

That would be in the bit `wData << id << rate << hours;`

I've done some poking around (I really like to try to solve these on my own) but I can't pinpoint precisely what's going on. I feel like it might be something really obvious that I'm brainfarting on.

Comment: In the time it took me to write a short answer, ten answers showed up. That's amazing response! There are so many helpful people on StackOverflow.

Comment: There really are. This is my first time using it. I totally appreciate all this help.

Comment: Well, hopefully you'll be back often and as you learn you'll be able to help pass on the knowledge to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `>>` not `<<` to read from an input stream. Think of these operators as arrows pointing in the direction the data moves.

Comment: Thank you! I initially thought that, too, but I ended up with an std error so I kind of let it go. This time, though, it worked, probably because I repositioned some of the other code.

Answer (score 3):

```
wData << id << rate << hours;
```

`wData` is `ifstream` object,
you are using `<<` with `wData` to `output` something. There is no `<<` defined for `ifstream`. `ifstream` is used  to read something with `>>` operator from file. Therefore, you have that error message.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to output to an input stream. Use `>>` instead.

Edit: clearly you've got your answer in spades :) Anyway, you should consider checking `wData.fail()` and `wData.eof()` to determine if there was some bad data or a premature end of file, respectively. Also, for future reference, there are streams that you can both insert into and extract from (anything inheriting from `iostream`).

Answer (score 1):

`wData` is an `ifstream`, it is meant for input (>>) not output (<<).

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

Answer (score 1):

Wrong direction, do this:

```
 wData >> id >> rate >> hours;
```

instead of:

```
 wData << id << rate << hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not output in an ifstream. What you need to be able to perform read is an ofstream. But it seems you mean to be reading from `wData` so probably all you need to do is to use double "more than"(`>>`) instead of double less than(`<<`).

Answer (score 0):

ifstream has only the `>>` operator defined.
`>>` is used for input.
You need the `ofstream` object in order to output something.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this:

```
wData << id << rate << hours;
```

be

```
 wData >> id >> rate >> hours;
```

??

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream wData;
```

This is an `input` file stream. U can't use `<<` operator on it. 
Just like you can't do `cin<<`

Comment: Haha, thanks guys. I figured it was something simple that I was blanking on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of it as input being input into the program (from the file). And output being output to the file (from the program). So you want to use an output stream, not an input stream.